# If statement using vhdl-counter

Tags: if-statement, vhdl, fpga

It'z DFF counter counts from 0 to 10, and from 10 to 0. There z switch to switch between Ascending/Descending. On of the guys in this website helped me to solve the if statement problem but it looks itz not allowed to use it outside the process , si if any one could help and have any idea to use when istead  . would be perfect. using planahead to design this counter

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity counter_10 is
port(
     clk, reset, pause: in std_logic;
     q: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end counter_10;

architecture arc_counter of counter_10 is
constant M: integer:=10;
signal r_reg: unsigned(3 downto 0);
signal r_next: unsigned(3 downto 0);
begin
process(clk, reset, pause)
begin
if(reset='1') then r_reg <=(others=>'0');
     elsif pause = '1' then
     r_reg<=r_reg;
     elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then
           r_reg<=r_next;
end if;
end process;
------------------------------------------------------------------------

if (inc_dec='1') then
   if (r_reg=(M-1)) then
        r_next <= (others=>'0');
   else 
        r_reg+1;
   end if; 
elsif (inc_dec='0') then
   if (r_reg=(M-10)) then
        r_next <=  to_unsigned(9, 4);
   else
        r_reg-1;
   end if;
end if;
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--Output logic
q<= std_logic_vector(r_reg);
end arc_counter;
```

The error still the same :

```
 [HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "if". 
 [HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "then". 
 [HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "else". 
 [HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "then". 

 [HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "then". 
 [HDLCompiler 806] Syntax error near "else".
```

Comment: An if statement is a sequential statement, found either in a process statement, a loop statement or a subprogram and not in an architecture body.  Next time consider providing a Minimal, Verifiable and Complete example, which your first question was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice your missing an port with mode in for inc_dec.

As mentioned in the comment your if statement isn't a concurrent statement and needs to go in a process.

Your increments and decrements for r_next aren't correct for VHDL.

The pause shouldn't be asynchronous  It infers a latch following the r_reg register.

Fix all those and it looks something like this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter_10 is
    port (
         clk:       in  std_logic;
         reset:     in  std_logic;
         pause:     in  std_logic;
         inc_dec:   in  std_logic;                    -- ADDED
         q:         out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end counter_10;

architecture arc_counter of counter_10 is
    -- constant M: integer := 10;  -- not needed
    signal r_reg: unsigned(3 downto 0);
    signal r_next: unsigned(3 downto 0);
begin
UNLABELED:
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
    if reset = '1' then 
        r_reg <= (others=>'0');
    -- elsif pause = '1' then
        -- r_reg <= r_reg;
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' and  not pause = '1' then
        r_reg <= r_next;
    end if;
    end process;
ADDED_PROCESS:
    process  (inc_dec, r_reg)
    begin
        if inc_dec = '1' then
            if r_reg = 9 then -- r_reg = M - 1 then
                 r_next <= (others => '0');
            else 
                 r_next <= r_reg + 1;  -- r_reg+1;
            end if; 
        elsif inc_dec = '0' then
            if r_reg = 0 then -- r_reg = M - 10 then
                 r_next <=  to_unsigned(9, 4);
            else
                 r_next <= r_reg - 1;   -- r_reg-1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
--Output 
    q<= std_logic_vector(r_reg);
end arc_counter;
```

And about now someone is bound to chime in and write that the two processes can be consolidated.

And that could look something like:

```
architecture foo of counter_10 is
    -- constant M: integer := 10;  -- not needed
    signal r_reg: unsigned(3 downto 0);
    signal r_next: unsigned(3 downto 0);
begin
SINGLE_PROCESS:
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
    if reset = '1' then 
        r_reg <= (others=>'0');
    -- elsif pause = '1' then
        -- r_reg <= r_reg;
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' and  not pause = '1' then
        if inc_dec = '1' then
            if r_reg = 9 then
                r_reg <= (others => '0');
            else
                r_reg <= r_reg + 1;
            end if;
        elsif inc_dec = '0' then   -- and this could be simply else
            if r_reg = 0 then
                r_reg <= to_unsigned(9, 4);
            else
                r_reg <= r_reg - 1;
            end if;
        end if;
        r_reg <= r_next;
    end if;
    end process;
--Output 
    q<= std_logic_vector(r_reg);
end architecture;
```

Subject to further improvements or alternate implementations.